# stripe.js why error is not showing up

Tags: javascript, laravel

Why I can't get error message? now when i click submit button server redirects me to the post and shows me unique Token, but it's not how it have to work..

```
   (function() {

    var StripeBilling = {
        init: function() {
            this.form = $('#billing-form');
            this.submitButton = this.form.find('input[type=submit]');
            this.submitButtonValue = this.submitButton.val();

            var stripeKey = $('meta[name="publishable-key"]').attr('content');

            Stripe.setPublishableKey(stripeKey);

            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            this.form.on('submit', $.proxy(this.sendToken, this));
        },

        sendToken: function(event) {
            this.submitButton.val('One Moment...').prop('disabled', true);

             Stripe.card.createToken({
                  number: $('.card-number').val(),
                  cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                  exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                  exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
                }, stripeResponseHandler);

            event.preventDefault();
        },

        stripeResponseHandler: function(status, response) {


            if(response.error) {
                this.form.find('.payment-errors').show().text(response.error.message);
                return this.submitButton.prop('disabled', false).val(this.submitButtonValue);
            }
            else{

            $('<input>', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'stripeToken',
                value: response.id

            }).appendTo(this.form);
}
            //this.form[0].submit();


        }

    };

    StripeBilling.init();


})();
```

It's creating a token, but token must be created only when data is typed in right! Thank you!

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example? Have you tried to manually inspect the HTTP request/response using browser developer tools? Have you tried to inspect the entire response object?

Comment: when i click on submit button it shows up me blank page with :
`array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "UTHBUHpLfBYKD8f6T5td6YbWx93pcJi0tjaFO5U8"
]` but the problem is... It's not cheking errors

Comment: I would, at first, move the preventDefault as a first line of the code and add a `return false` at the bottom or add this on top

`e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`

Adding a reproducible example would help debugging your issue